# wso2 esb out of memory when clients disconnects

Tags: out-of-memory, wso2-esb

I've a wso2esb 4.8.0 running with some proxies deployed in.

All works great until clients that are calling the proxies begin to disconnect, before receiving the response from the esb.

after few minutes the ESB goes in outOfmemory error.

the average size of requests is: 1.2 Kb.
the average size of responses is: 1.6 Mb.

the server is running with: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m.

In the heap dump I can see that the major classes retaining memory are java.lang.Thread (PassThroghtMessageProcessor), lot of and all with size of 36Mb .

sometimes there is also this error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

if clients don't disconnect everything works good.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If clients are disconnecting, maybe the root cause is that your back end is taking too long to answer.

There are a few thing you can do:

1. Decrease the timeout for back end responses, so messages don't pile up on the ESB
2. Use the throttling mediator or handler in order to reject messages above a certain rate.

Both are targeted at the symptoms (oom at the ESB). Other than that, it may be necessary an integration model redesign, maybe using a store-and-forward approach.

Comment: any smarter solution?

Comment: Not sure what "smarter" means, but a more pragmatic approach would be an increase in the amount of heap memory. Change the value of -Xmx parameter to something like -Xms4096m and see if the problem persists.

Comment: the problem is with ws security, alias rampart. I remove the <enableSec /> in the proxy and now everything is running nice. Of course this is not the solution, I have to understand why rampart retains the memory, good luck :-(

Comment: Try replacing the PassThrough transport by the NHTTP transport. The main benefit of the former is that it can forward the message without the need of building it in memory. Since you´ve enabled security, this is no longer possible since rampart must read the full message content into memory in order to validate it.

To change transports you have to edit the axis2.xml file located in the repository/conf/axis2 folder. In the standard distribution there is an axis2_nhttp.xml file that you can use as-is. Just rename it to axis2.xml and restart the ESB